# pandas groupby with Group Limits

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a list of transactions from Seller A to Buyers A, B & C. I would like to `groupby` these transactions in `pandas` by date, price and seller, but no grouped transaction can be made up of more than 1 Buyer A, B, and C individual transaction legs. For example, an aggregate transaction cannot contain two Buyer A sub-transactions (same goes for Buyer B & C).

Here is an example list of transactions:

[image: example]

```
date        price   quantity    seller      buyer
1/1/2022    100     10          Seller A    Buyer A
1/1/2022    100     5           Seller A    Buyer B
1/1/2022    100     3           Seller A    Buyer C
1/1/2022    100     10          Seller A    Buyer A
1/1/2022    100     5           Seller A    Buyer B
1/1/2022    100     3           Seller A    Buyer C
1/1/2022    100     10          Seller A    Buyer A
1/1/2022    100     5           Seller A    Buyer B
1/2/2022    100     10          Seller A    Buyer A
1/2/2022    100     5           Seller A    Buyer B
1/2/2022    100     3           Seller A    Buyer C
```

Here is the desired result:

[image]

```
date        price   quantity    seller      Buyer A_quantity    Buyer B_quantity    Buyer C_quantity
1/1/2022    100     18          Seller A    10                  5                   3
1/1/2022    100     18          Seller A    10                  5                   3
1/1/2022    100     15          Seller A    10                  5                   NA
1/2/2022    100     18          Seller A    10                  5                   3
```

I am trying to perform the grouping, sum the quantities, and then unstack the Buyer A, B and C quantities. Currently I cannot unstack, however, since the date, price and seller fields are not unique (see the orange and blue rows in the example).

Comment: Can you post your data as a table/data screenshots are not an acceptable form of sharing data as it makes it impossible to copy and paste

Comment: It is not clear to me how you can differentiate groups. For example, why are the two yellow rows a single transaction and not two separate transactions each with one buyer?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your sellers and buyers are sorted in the desired order already, first have he missing transaction number (missing from your data) based on `date`, `buyer` and `seller` as:

```
df['Transaction_number'] = df.groupby(['date','seller', 'buyer']).cumcount()+1 
df
```

Now your df should look like:

| date | price | quantity | seller | buyer | Transaction_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2022 | 100 | 10 | Seller A | Buyer A | 1 |
| 1/1/2022 | 100 | 5 | Seller A | Buyer B | 1 |
| 1/1/2022 | 100 | 3 | Seller A | Buyer C | 1 |
| 1/1/2022 | 100 | 10 | Seller A | Buyer A | 2 |
| 1/1/2022 | 100 | 5 | Seller A | Buyer B | 2 |
| 1/1/2022 | 100 | 3 | Seller A | Buyer C | 2 |
| 1/1/2022 | 100 | 10 | Seller A | Buyer A | 3 |
| 1/1/2022 | 100 | 5 | Seller A | Buyer B | 3 |
| 1/2/2022 | 100 | 10 | Seller A | Buyer A | 1 |
| 1/2/2022 | 100 | 5 | Seller A | Buyer B | 1 |
| 1/2/2022 | 100 | 3 | Seller A | Buyer C | 1 |

On which you can run a simple `pivot_table()` to get your desired result:

```
df.pivot_table(index=['date','Transaction_number', 'price', 'seller'],
               columns='buyer', 
               values='quantity', 
               aggfunc='sum').reset_index()
```

| date | Transaction_number | price | seller | Buyer A | Buyer B | Buyer C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2022 | 1 | 100 | Seller A | 10 | 5 | 3 |
| 1/1/2022 | 2 | 100 | Seller A | 10 | 5 | 3 |
| 1/1/2022 | 3 | 100 | Seller A | 10 | 5 | nan |
| 1/2/2022 | 1 | 100 | Seller A | 10 | 5 | 3 |

To match your exact output you may rename columns, add total quantity as `quantity` column and drop `Transaction_number` as:

```
 pivot=df.pivot_table(index=['date','Transaction_number', 'price', 'seller'],
                     columns='buyer', 
                     values='quantity', 
                     aggfunc='sum')\
        .reset_index()\
        .drop(columns=['Transaction_number'])\
        .rename(columns=lambda x: f"{x}_quantity" if x.startswith('Buyer') else x)
pivot.insert(2, 'quantity', pivot.iloc[:, 3:].sum(axis=1))
pivot
```

| date | price | quantity | seller | Buyer A_quantity | Buyer B_quantity | Buyer C_quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2022 | 100 | 18 | Seller A | 10 | 5 | 3 |
| 1/1/2022 | 100 | 18 | Seller A | 10 | 5 | 3 |
| 1/1/2022 | 100 | 15 | Seller A | 10 | 5 | nan |
| 1/2/2022 | 100 | 18 | Seller A | 10 | 5 | 3 |

Note that: this assumes `price` is either constant or you want to group by it. If neither is the case, you can remove `price` from pivot table completely or aggregate it as well.